# API Gateway: how to I deploy an iOS Client API for specific version of API Gateway?

Tags: ios, aws-api-gateway

I am using AWS API Gateway with an iOS Swift app.

From Github I've gotten the latest version of the iOS AWS frameworks (currently 2.4.9). However, the AWS API Gateway console kicks out Client code that is incompatible.

From AWS 2.4.9 AWSAPIGatewayClient.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration;
```

From API Gateway console generated Client code XxClient.swift (line 124)

```
init(configuration: AWSServiceConfiguration) {
    super.init()

    self.configuration = configuration
```

Because v2.4.9 defines `configuration` as `readonly` the generated Client code doesn't work - it's out of date.

Can I generate a compatible set of Client files? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API Gateway generated SDK for Swift also provides with a file named `AWSApiGatewayBridge.h` which is imported via the bridging header of your app(showed in `Bridging_Header.h`).

The Generated SDK won't work without `AWSApiGatewayBridge.h` imported in your project.

The SDK version 2.4.9 is the latest version and will work correctly.

Thanks,
Rohan

Comment: Thanks. With the SDK being Swift I was caught out that my Objective C bridge file would need an addition. Worth documenting this?

Comment: add #import "AWSApiGatewayBridge.h" to your ObjC bridge header file

Comment: I believe its a part of the README.md file included in the download.

Comment: The README.md contains a link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html but I couldn't find any mention of 'bridge'